# Javascript jQuery Ajax method not always working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am developing a chat application and found a bug which I can't solve, I'm stuck :/

Basically: I have two different LocalStorage variables (`kontakte`, a new contact will be add when you are writing a message to a person to whom you have never written before, `"chat_" + email`, there are all messages you and your current contact have written). My method will run every 4.5 seconds, it tests if there is a new message (`data != null`), and when that is true the method will look if you are currently at the chat page from who you have got a new message (`data[neuenabf - 4] == seite5_empfemail && seiten_aktpossonder == 5`).

If that is also true it adds the new message to the chat (`seite_5main.innerHTML = seite_5main.innerHTML`...), when the message begin is equal to "!§?%&&45es", "!§?%&&45ds", "!§?%&&45as" an extra box (popup) is shown

Here is the problem, about every 4 - 5 times a new message isn't shown in the chat. Also you can't see this new message in the firefox F12-console when you look at ajax request (every 4 - 5 messages you can't see the 4th / 5th message). 
Then what makes this more crazy is that the new message is surely added to the list of messages(the localstorage "chat_"+email)!?

The method:

```
var seite_5nnnspeicher1 = [];
var seite5_spielzeitb;
function neuenachrichtabf() {
    $.ajax({
        dataType: "JSON",
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://...de/ajax/chat.php',
        data: {sender: LOCemail, methode: "s2"},
        success: function (data) {
          if (data != null) {
            for (neuenabf = data.length-1; neuenabf > 0; neuenabf = neuenabf - 5) {
                if ((data[neuenabf-4] == seite5_empfemail) && seiten_aktpossonder == 5) {//Wenn eine neue Nachricht kommt und man aktuell bei dem Kontakt ist wo eine neue Nachricht kommt
                    if (data[neuenabf-1].startsWith("!§?%&&45es")) {
                        seite5_spielzeitb = 'Um '+data[neuenabf-1].slice(16, 19)+data[neuenabf-1].slice(19, 21)+' Uhr, den '+data[neuenabf-1].slice(10, 12)+'-'+data[neuenabf-1].slice(13, 15);
                        seite_5main.innerHTML = seite_5main.innerHTML + '<div id="spielanfrage_s5bekommen" style="background: white; font-size: 15px; position: relative; margin-top: 8px; margin-left: 12px; border-radius: 2px; padding: 8px; box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); color: black; display: table-cell; max-width: 80%; white-space: normal; float: left; clear: both;"><font style="color: #4285f4;"><b>Spielanfrage:</b></font></br><font style="color: #656565;">'+seite5_spielzeitb+'</font></br><div style="width: 50%; height: 40px; color: #656565; float: left; line-height: 40px;" onclick="s5_spabl(\''+seite5_spielzeitb+'\')">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<img src="img/delete.png" style="position: absolute; height: 15px; margin-top: 12px;"></div><div style="width: 50%; height: 40px; float: left; color: #656565; line-height: 40px; position: relative;" onclick="s5_spakt(\''+seite5_spielzeitb+'\')">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<img src="img/done.png" style="position: absolute; height: 24px; top: 8px;"></div><font style="color: #ccc; font-size: 11px; float: right;">'+data[neuenabf]+'</font><div class="arrow-left" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: -9px;"></div></div>';
        }
        else if(data[neuenabf-1].startsWith("!§?%&&45ds"))
        {
          seite5_spielzeitb = 'Um '+data[neuenabf-1].slice(16, 19)+data[neuenabf-1].slice(19, 21)+' Uhr, den '+data[neuenabf-1].slice(10, 12)+'-'+data[neuenabf-1].slice(13, 15);
          document.getElementById("spielanfrage_s5geschickt").innerHTML = '<font style="color: #4285f4;"><b>Spielanfrage:</b></br></font><font style="color: #656565;">'+seite5_spielzeitb+'</font></br></br><font style="color: #f44336; text-align: center;"><italic>Abgelehnt</italic></font><div class="arrow-right" style="position: absolute; bottom: 0px; right: -9px;"></div>';  
          document.getElementById("spielanfrage_s5geschickt").id = '';
          s5_spabls = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("chat_"+seite5_empfemail));
          index_ersetzen(s5_spabls, "ds");
        }
        else if(data[neuenabf-1].startsWith("!§?%&&45as"))
        {
          seite5_spielzeitb = 'Um '+data[neuenabf-1].slice(16, 19)+data[neuenabf-1].slice(19, 21)+' Uhr, den '+data[neuenabf-1].slice(10, 12)+'-'+data[neuenabf-1].slice(13, 15);
          document.getElementById("spielanfrage_s5geschickt").innerHTML = '<font style="color: #4285f4;"><b>Spielanfrage:</b></br></font><font style="color: #656565;">'+seite5_spielzeitb+'</font></br></br><font style="color: #009688;">Angenommen</font><div class="arrow-right" style="position: absolute; bottom: 0px; right: -9px;"></div>';  
          document.getElementById("spielanfrage_s5geschickt").id = '';
          s5_spabls = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("chat_"+seite5_empfemail));
          index_ersetzen(s5_spabls, "as");  
        }
        else
        {
          seite_5main.innerHTML = seite_5main.innerHTML + '<div style="background: white; font-size: 15px; position: relative; margin-top: 8px; margin-left: 12px; border-radius: 2px; padding: 8px; box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); color: black; display: table-cell; max-width: 80%; white-space: normal; float: left; clear: both;">'+data[neuenabf-1]+'</br><font style="color: #ccc; font-size: 11px; float: left;">'+data[neuenabf]+'</font><div class="arrow-left" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: -9px;"></div></div>';             
        }

        //ZUR LOKALEN STORAGE HINZUFÜGEN
        if (localStorage.getItem("chat_"+seite5_empfemail))
        {
          seite_5nnnspeicher1 = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("chat_"+seite5_empfemail));
          seite_5nnnspeicher1.push(seite5_empfemail, data[neuenabf], data[neuenabf-1]);
          localStorage.setItem("chat_"+seite5_empfemail, JSON.stringify(seite_5nnnspeicher1));
        }
        else
        {
          localStorage.setItem("chat_"+seite5_empfemail, JSON.stringify([seite5_empfemail, data[neuenabf], data[neuenabf-1]]));
        }

        if (localStorage.getItem("kontakte"))
        {
          seite_5nnnspeicher = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("kontakte"));
          if(index_finden(seite_5nnnspeicher, seite5_empfemail) === 1) //Wenn der aktuelle Kontakt schon in den Kontakten ist -> Nichts passiert
          {
          }
          else //Wenn der aktuelle noch nicht in den Kontakten ist -> Kontakt hinzufügen
          {  
            seite_5nnnspeicher.push(seite5_empfemail, seite_5name, seite_5lk, 'a');
            localStorage.setItem("kontakte", JSON.stringify(seite_5nnnspeicher));                     
          }
        }
        else //Wenn noch keine Kontakte da sind -> Kontakt hinzufügen
        {
          localStorage.setItem("kontakte", JSON.stringify([seite5_empfemail, seite_5name, seite_5lk, 'a']));      
        }
      }
      //---------//
      else
      {
        if (localStorage.getItem("chat_"+data[neuenabf-4]))
        {
          seite_5nnnspeicher1 = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("chat_"+data[neuenabf-4]));
          seite_5nnnspeicher1.push(data[neuenabf-4], data[neuenabf], data[neuenabf-1]);
          localStorage.setItem("chat_"+data[neuenabf-4], JSON.stringify(seite_5nnnspeicher1));
        }
        else
        {
          localStorage.setItem("chat_"+data[neuenabf-4], JSON.stringify([data[neuenabf-4], data[neuenabf], data[neuenabf-1]]));
        }

        if (localStorage.getItem("kontakte"))
        {
          seite_5nnnspeicher = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("kontakte"));
          if(index_finden(seite_5nnnspeicher, data[neuenabf-4]) === 1) //Wenn der aktuelle Kontakt schon in den Kontakten ist -> Nichts passiert
          {
          }
          else //Wenn der aktuelle noch nicht in den Kontakten ist -> Kontakt hinzufügen
          {  
            seite_5nnnspeicher.push(data[neuenabf-4], data[neuenabf-3], data[neuenabf-2], 'a');
            localStorage.setItem("kontakte", JSON.stringify(seite_5nnnspeicher));                     
          }
        }
        else //Wenn noch keine Kontakte da sind -> Kontakt hinzufügen
        {
          localStorage.setItem("kontakte", JSON.stringify([data[neuenabf-4], data[neuenabf-3], data[neuenabf-2], 'a']));      
        }
        //---//
        if (localStorage.getItem("LOCneuenawo_"+data[neuenabf-4]))
        {
          localStorage.setItem("LOCneuenawo_"+data[neuenabf-4], parseInt(localStorage.getItem("LOCneuenawo_"+data[neuenabf-4]))+1);
        }
        else
        {
          localStorage.setItem("LOCneuenawo_"+data[neuenabf-4], "1");
        }
        document.getElementById("main_menu_nkreis").style.visibility = "visible";
      }
    }
    seite4_kontakteanz();
    $('#seite_5main').scrollTop(1000000);
    }
},
error: function()
{
}
});
}

function index_finden(dasarray,wert)
{
  for (var i = 0; i < dasarray.length; i++)  
  {
    if (dasarray[i] === wert)  
    {  
      return 1;
    }
  }
}
```

How can that be, isnt it impossible?

Comment: Of course it is possible. However, you won't be able to understand the reason why since you have neutered your `error` handler. That's the equivalent of an empty `catch` block, you should remedy that.

Comment: Change your error to the following and post what you are getting:

error: function(err)
{
    console.log(err);
}

Comment: But its only sometimes not working right

Comment: Try to log the error response to maybe see what gives. Won't know until you try

Comment: There is no error the massages are stored but sometimes not showen in the current chat

Comment: You mix JQuery and document.getElementById. You can improve your code by using `$("#spielanfrage_s5geschickt")` instead of `document.getElementById("spielanfrage_s5geschickt")`


You also can build DOM objects and use them as templates so you don't have all the html in your function.

Comment: Ok but thats not the problem

Comment: I know, the above coment is a suggestion

Comment: Is it passible that the Script is to busy?

Answer (score -1):

`Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks are deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. To prepare your code for their eventual removal, use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead.` cite of http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

so use better the pattern:

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: "JSON",
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://...de/ajax/chat.php',
    data: {
      sender: LOCemail,
      methode: "s2"
    },
  })
    .error(function( err ) {
      alert( "error: " + err );
    });
    .done(function( data ) {
      // Your function as above
    });
```

As you commented above there are no ajax errors, so I suppose that you have other problems in your scripts which should be discussed in an other question.

*If you like provide a fiddle with your html & css. I'll have a look on that*

Comment: The Problem is that i cant post or fiddle the wohle code, that are more than 3000 lines. The mistake/bug have to be in my posted code.